# Get pairs of keys (n0, _), (n1, _) with maximum values for each key pair (n0, a), (n0, b) in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-analysis, bigdata

Suppose we have a dict like:

```
os_stats = {
    ('USA', 'Mac OS X'): 1,
    ('Mexico', 'iOS'): 3,
    ('USA', 'Windows XP'): 2, 
    ('Germany', 'Windows 7'): 9,
    ('Germany', 'Windows XP'): 7, 
    ('Mexico', 'Windows XP'): 2,
    ...
}
```

And I want an output like:

```
os_preferences = {
     ('Mexico', 'iOS'): 3, 
     ('USA', 'Windows XP'): 2,
     ('Germany', 'Windows 7'): 9, 
      ...
}
```

Where only the highest value for each country is presented.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you try writing the code to do it?

Comment: I am currently trying, but ATM have no solution

Comment: Are you sure that data structure is the best way of representing your data? It may be more convenient for you to have a nested dictionary instead, so that you can easily access groups of key-values related to the same country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dict comprehension does it:

```
{country:{os:count} for (country,os),count in sorted(os_stats.items(), key=lambda rec:rec[1])}
```

The first part is this:

```
sorted(os_stats.items(), key=lambda rec:rec[1])
```

That produces:

```
[(('USA', 'Mac OS X'), 1),
 (('Mexico', 'Windows XP'), 2),
 (('USA', 'Windows XP'), 2),
 (('Mexico', 'iOS'), 3),
 (('Germany', 'Windows XP'), 7),
 (('Germany', 'Windows 7'), 9)]
```

Note that it's sorted by ascending order of the count field (`rec[1]`).

The rest is just massaging the data into a single `dict`, which has the effect of discarding the smaller values by overwriting them as it goes with the larger ones.

Comment: You are going to have to translate the output of that comprehension into the desired form, if the output of your comprehension is `d`, the desired output will be `{(p[0], p[1].keys()[0]): p[1].values()[0] for p in d.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/) gets the job done in 3 lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(os_stats, index=['index']).transpose()
os_preferences = df[df['index'] == df.groupby(level=[0])['index'].transform(max)].to_dict()['index']

# output:
# {('Mexico', 'iOS'): 3, 
#  ('USA', 'Windows XP'): 2, 
#  ('Germany', 'Windows 7'): 9}
```

Comment: This is so totally gonna blow OP's mind.  +1 for Pandas.

Comment: Actually I am restricted to pure python. That's why I am not using pandas.